# how to define boundingRect for user defined text

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

i have to define an QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem  which  displays a text using the data given by the user . 
 so i need some suggestions on how to define the boundingRect for the user defined text as the text size varies in length .

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html

Comment: thanks im following it .